# Two PCs with own routers on the same LAN

Tags: lan, broadband, dhcp-server

I want to put an additional Windows 10 PCs, with its own broadband service provider, on the same Ethernet LAN as others that already have a different broadband service provider.  Are there likely to be problems with this?  I want the additional PC to continue to use its own broadband connection.

Here's why...
One has a very slow, but unlimited monthly download quota, which I use for lengthy downloads such as films.  The other is reasonably fast, but expensive, especially if I exceed the monthly quota.

Currently, I transfer files through a USB2 link, which is, of course, rather slow.

There is a similar question to this that mentions DHCP as a potential issue.  I regret, I don't know what DHCP is, and the answer given was technically beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

This can work OK **if** you provide static IP addresses to both computers.  This is to overcome the exact issue you mentioned - DHCP.  DHCP is a way for computers to automatically get IP addresses without them being manually assigned.  This is standard with residential internet service.  If you put everything on the same LAN, then you not only have two computers sharing the network, but also two DHCP servers (which are basically built into the cable modems).  If a computer powers on and sees two DHCP servers, it could get an assignment from either one of them.  You don't want this to happen, which is why you'll need to assign IP addresses manually.  Actually, the key piece is the *gateway*.  That's the deciding factor on which outbound route each computer uses to get to the internet.

Another potential pitfall is that each cable modem might be set up to assign IP addresses in a different subnet (10.0.0.0 vs. 192.168.0.0 for example).  If you want the two computers to be able to talk to each other, you'll need these to be the same.  Most cable modems today have built-in NAT, and it's generally configurable.  You'll need to know how to set this up, or find someone who does.

The bottom line:  yes you can make it work, but you'll need some networking knowledge to get the configurations right.

Comment: Static IP on just the one computer would do it too right? One computer with a static IP and the new ISP router with DHCP disabled having a non-DHCP static IP assigned to it too on the LAN side. The PC that connects to it will point to it for its default gateway in it's static IP configurations, right? You need to assign static IP to the new ISP router on shared LAN side, and only statically assign computers on that LAN which you want to use that default gateway as the default gateway in the IP configs, right?

Comment: Oh dear!  I'm wishing I hadn't asked this question.  I really did not want to get this deep into network configuration.  I suspect this answer, along with its accompanying comment, is the right one, but I regret to say that I'm not going to try it.